# Not displaying tiles in MOBAC with custom Maperitive tiles source

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to generate a .sqlitedb map file for an Android app containing the map of a small city, I tried using Mobile Atlas Creator 1.9.14 by itself, but it only displays red crosses, no tiles(I use a proxy with authentication, and i configured it on the settings/network tab), I don't know what to do there. I then heard about Maperitive and I downloaded a .osm.pbf file from GeoFabrik to use as source, generated a Tiles folder i needed and followed [this instructions](https://mobac.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/mobac/trunk/MOBAC/mapsources/Example%20custom%20tile%20files%20source.xml) to use it on MOBAC as custom source.

It does nothing at all, I still get the same red crosses everywhere, but everyone else seems to have it working just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, the template file from MOBAC has a lot of comments. After removing them it worked! My xml file is now very simple, even the `<sourceType>` seems not to be necessary. Here it is:

```
<localTileFiles><name>Maperitive Tiles</name><sourceFolder>/ed/map_composer/Maperitive/Tiles</sourceFolder><backgroundColor>#00000000</backgroundColor></localTileFiles>
```